# If $A^k$ consistently approximates $\nabla^2f(x^k)$ with $x^k\to x^*$ and $\nabla^2f(x^*)$ regular, then the $A^k$ are regular, too

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, numerical-methods

Let's call $\left\{A^k\right\}\subseteq\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ a **consistent approximation** of $\left\{B^k\right\}\subseteq\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ iff $$\left\|A_k-B_k\right\|\stackrel{k\to\infty}{\to}0\;.$$ Can we show, that if each $B^k$ (or at least $B_0$) is regular, the $A^k$ must be regular, too?

---

As you might know, the following can be shown:

> Let $A,B\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ with $$\left\|I-BA\right\|<1\;$$ Then, $A,B$ are regular and $$\left\|A^{-1}\right\|\le\frac{\left\|B\right\|}{1-\left\|I-BA\right\|}\;.$$

For example: Let $f\in C^2(\mathbb R^n)$ and $x^*\in\mathbb R^n$ such that $\nabla^2 f(x^*)$ is regular. Then, if $\left\{A^k\right\}$ is a consistent approximation of $\left\{B_k:=\nabla^2f(x^*)\right\}$, we can conclude, that the $A_k$ are regular and $$\left\|A_k^{-1}\right\|\le C$$ for some $C>0$.

Now, I would really like to extend this statement to the following scenario: Let $\left\{x^k\right\}\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ be convergent to $x^*$.

> **Claim**$\;\;\;$*In presence of further assumptions*, if $\left\{A_k\right\}$ is a consistent approximation of $\left\{\nabla^2f(x^k)\right\}$, then the $A_k$ are regular and uniformly bounded.

Can we prove the claim under suitable assumptions?

Comment: It is a clear no: Take $A_k = 0$ and $B_k = \frac1k I$.

Comment: 0 would not approximate a second derivative for any interesting function.

Comment: @mathreadler it does what is demanded ... One could try to fix the question somehow ...

Answer (score 1):

The claim in the title and at the end is true. Irregular matrices form a hypersurface, thus the regular matrices form an open (and dense) set. If $B_*=\lim B_k$ is regular, then there is an open ball (in whatever norm in the matrix space) around $B_*$ of regular matrices. The sequence $B_k$ must eventually lie inside this ball, and since $\lim\|A_k-B_k\|=0$ also the sequence $A_k$ must enter this ball.

Thus there has to exist some index $K$ so that for all $k\ge K$ both the matrices $A_k$ and $B_k$ are regular.